# http on subdomain redirects to main domain; subdomain works with https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, subdomain, redirect

I have a root domain `https://example.com` and subdomain `https://sub.example.com`, and a Positive SSL on the root domain `example.com`

My problem is that whenever I try to visit `http://sub.example.com` I am correctly redirected to `https://example.com`, but when I visit `https://sub.example.com`, I am not redirected. How can I also redirect `https://sub.example.com` to `https://example.com` ?

`.htaccess` in subdomain:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 10 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 hours"
</IfModule>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.example\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are only looking HTTP requests

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Try to add same rules with HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.sub\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that's exactly what I was after. I thought I tried it already but I must have done it incorrectly.